# Send mail does not send to external on live site, will only work on visual studio debug mode

Tags: c#, email, iis, visual-studio-2012

I'm having an odd issue, my send mail function was not sending emails to external recipients. So I debugged the application in visual studio put some breakpoints in and it does send the emails and I receive them.

So now how do I debug why it doesn't work on the live site and it does in debug mode?

here is my send mail code

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress("internaladdress@domain.com"));
foreach (var Supplier in tblRequest.GroupBy(r => r.SupplierID).OrderBy(g => g.First().tblSuppliers.Supplier))
{
    //mail.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(Supplier.First().tblSuppliers.EmailAddress));
}
mail.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress("externaladdress@outlook.com"));
mail.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress("internaladdress@domain.com"));
mail.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress("internaladdress@domain.com"));
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
var SMTPCredentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("DOMAIN\\USER", "Password");
client.Credentials = SMTPCredentials;
client.Port = 25;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.Host = "IP ADDRESS OF MAIL SERVER";
mail.Subject = "IS" + intEmailQuoteID.ToString("D5") + " Quote";
//mail.Body += "<html>";
//mail.Body += "<head>";
//mail.Body += "<title></title>";
mail.Body += "<style>body {font-family:calibri;} table {border-collapse:collapse;} table, th, td {border: 1px solid black; padding:10px;}</style>";
//mail.Body += "</head>";
//mail.Body += "<body>";
mail.Body += "<p>Could you please provide us with prices for the below? Any questions please reply to this email address.</p>";
if (tblRequest.First().tblQuotes.EmailNotes != "")
    mail.Body += "<p>" + tblRequest.First().tblQuotes.EmailNotes + "</p>";
mail.Body +="<p>Thank You</p>";
mail.Body += "<table style='width:700px'>";
mail.Body += "<tr>";
mail.Body += "<td style='background:#CCC;'>Quote Reference No:</td>";
mail.Body += "<td>IS" + intEmailQuoteID.ToString("D5") + "</td>";
mail.Body += "<td style='background:#CCC;'>Orginator:</td>";
mail.Body += "<td>" + helpers.GetUserName(tblRequest.First().tblQuotes.OriginatorID) + "</td>";
mail.Body += "<td style='background:#CCC;'>Request Date:</td>";
mail.Body += "<td>" + tblRequest.First().tblQuotes.RequestDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "</td>";
mail.Body += "</tr>";
mail.Body += "</table>";
mail.Body += "<br />";
mail.Body += "<table style='width:700px'>";
mail.Body += "<thead>";
mail.Body += "<tr>";
mail.Body += "<th>Quantity</th>";
mail.Body += "<th>Item</th>";
mail.Body += "<th>Part No</th>";
mail.Body += "<th>Description</th>";
mail.Body += "</tr>";
mail.Body += "</thead>";
mail.Body += "<tbody>";
foreach (var mailItem in tblRequest.GroupBy(r => r.ItemID).OrderBy(g => g.First().tblItems.Name))
{
    mail.Body += "<tr>";
    mail.Body += "<td>" + mailItem.First().Quantity + "</td>";
    mail.Body += "<td>" + mailItem.First().tblItems.Name + "</td>";
    mail.Body += "<td>" + mailItem.First().tblItems.PartNo + "</td>";
    mail.Body += "<td>" + mailItem.First().tblItems.Description + "</td>";
    mail.Body += "</tr>";
}
mail.Body += "</tbody>";
mail.Body += "</table>";
//mail.Body += "</body>";
//mail.Body += "</html>";
try
{
    client.Send(mail);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ViewBag.Errors = ex.ToString();
}
```

Also, the internal mail gets received in both debug and on the live site (and the delivery notification) on the live site, I only get internal and nothing for external

Thanks

Comment: If it is not working for outside then it may be issue with the email server config.

Comment: sorry its an intranet application, so im internal in both tests, the test that fails is on the webserver and the test that works is on my host debugging

Comment: So, is it not sending to `externaladdress@outlook.com`?

Comment: correct (although external address is actually my outlook address), in debug it sends to both address, on the internal site, it only sends internally

Comment: What is this internal and outlook external address? I'm not sure. I got similar problem when my `from` add had no rights to send email. Talk to your network admin.

Comment: Also what exception are you getting on the server?

Comment: I am the network admin, i have added network credentials to the the smtp sender, so i should be seeing execptions on the mail server? ill check..